# Count the occurrence of one column based on another

Tags: python, group-by, count, multiple-columns, distinct

I have a dataframe like this

| System | package |
| --- | --- |
| mac | abc |
| mac | bcd |
| windows | bcd |
| mac | abc |

I want a code in python to get a dataframe like this

| System | count of distinct package |
| --- | --- |
| mac | 2 |
| windows | 1 |

Comment: Please post a portion of code that you've tried and point where are you stucked.

Comment: I tried this but it does not give me the result that I want result= df.groupby(['system','package'])['system'].count()

Comment: Check proposed solution. Note that I named columns as "a" and "b", so you would have to change it on your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={"a":["mac","mac","windows","mac",],"b": ["abc", "bcd", "bcd", "abc"]})
```

group it:

```
t.groupby('a').b.nunique()
```

output:

```
    a
mac        2
windows    1
Name: b, dtype: int64
```